# Can Photoshop Caption Digest metadata be added by another program?

Tags: c#, image, metadata, photoshop

I have to analyse a picture and figure out if it has been modified by Photoshop. Using [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) I got the following information (in the format of `Directory:TagName=TagDescription`):

- JPEG:Data Precision=8 bits
- JPEG:Image Height=1600 pixels
- JPEG:Image Width=1200 pixels
- JPEG:Number of Components=3
- JPEG:Component 1=Y component: Quantization table 0
- Sampling factors 2 horiz/2 vert
- JPEG:Component 2=Cb component: Quantization table 1
- Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
- JPEG:Component 3=Cr component: Quantization table 1
- Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
- JFIF:Version=1.1
- JFIF:Resolution Units=none
- JFIF:X Resolution=72 dots
- JFIF:Y Resolution=72 dots
- JFIF:Thumbnail Width Pixels=0
- JFIF:Thumbnail Height Pixels=0
- Exif IFD0:Orientation=Top
- left side (Horizontal / normal)
- Exif SubIFD:Color Space=sRGB
- Exif SubIFD:Exif Image Width=1200 pixels
- Exif SubIFD:Exif Image Height=1600 pixels
- Photoshop:Caption Digest=212 29 140 217 143 0 178 4 233 128 9 152 236 248 66 126
- File:File Name=mypicture.jpg
- File:File Size=175794 bytes
- File:File Modified Date=Thu Sep 29 14:22:44 +02:00 2016

Now, question is: can the `Photoshop:Caption Digest=212 29 140 217 143 0 178 4 233 128 9 152 236 248 66 126` metadata be generated by a program that is NOT Photoshop? Or is it an evidence that the image was photoshopped?

Comment: It's an indication, sure, but not conclusive evidence. It might just have been _saved_ in Photoshop, _without_ editing, and I'm fairly sure there are editors for this metadata. Though you can of course be sure that _something_ edited it; an image is not likely to come out of a camera with that kind of tag in it.

Comment: @Nyerguds as a matter of fact, about 40% of my dataset has this tag. I suppose this is added by cloud services to optimise images.

Comment: Yes, found this field in an iPhone 6 photo to which text had been added  via the Edit/Markup option. No Photoshop.